# How to "Enter group" without double clicking

Tags: inkscape

From the [Inkscape keyboard and mouse reference](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys048.html), *"For groups, double clicking performs the "Enter group" command (the group becomes a temporary layer)."*

This is great, but what if I can't easily double click on the group and I still want to enter it to paste or create elements within the group? For example, when the group is underneath another object it's impossible to double click on it. I can select it using Alt+click or by locating it in the XML editor. After I have it selected, is there a way I can enter the group without double clicking? (I don't want to have to move the item to the top, because I have an extensive and complicated stacking order.)

Answer (score 6):

Select the group and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the group.